# iOSアプリのViewでPDFを回転させたい

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c

Viewに表示させたPDFを、回転操作させる方法を探しています。
言語はObjective-Cです。
ご存知の方おりましたら教えていただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願い致します。